# how to get data from body parser in array using node js?

Tags: node.js, body-parser

Here I'm having no_of_devices which has three fields 'macAddress', 'useWith' and 'type' in a row, the count of row depends upon the number of devices selected from select field, so I'm using body-parser and i want to get all the row data which has name generated using for loop so all the rows having macAddress will have name='macAdd0',name="macAdd1" etc same goes with 'type' and 'useWith' field.

**HTML**

```
<select id="noOfDevice" class="form-control" name="noOfDevice" onchange="getDeviceCount(this)">
    <option selected value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>
    <option value="6">06</option>
    <option value="7">07</option>
    <option value="8">08</option>
    <option value="9">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    var macAdd;
    var useWith;
    var type;
    var noOfDevice = req.body.noOfDevice;
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfDevice; i++) {
        var k = i.toString();
        macAdd[i] = req.body.macAdd[i];
        useWith[i] = req.body.useWith[i];
        type[i] = req.body.type[i];
        //console.log(req.body.macAdd);
        process.deviceManger(macAdd[i], useWith[i], type[i]);
        console.log('Device' + i + 'Details Update');
    }
    function getDeviceCount(sel) {
        console.log("No of Device:" + sel.value);
        var currCount = sel.value;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < currCount; i++) {
            div.setAttribute('id', 'addElements');
            div.innerHTML += '<div class="row"><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-3"><label for="inputCity">Mac Address</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="macAdd" name="macAdd' + i + '"></div> <div class="form-group col-md-3"><label for="inputState">Type of Device</label> <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="deviceType' + i + '"> <option selected>Select</option> <option value="Irys Slate">Irys Slate</option> <option value="Irys Sling">Irys Sling</option> <option value="Irys Swing">Irys Swing</option> </select> </div> <div class="form-group col-md-3"> <label for="inputState">Use with</label> <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="useWith' + i + '"> <option selected>Select</option> <option value="All">All</option> <option value="Nconnect">Nconnect</option> <option value="Tiara">Tiara</option> <option value="Corona">Corona</option> <option value="TiaraMini">TiaraMini</option> <option value="Nconnect+Tiara">Nconnect+Tiara</option> <option value="Nconnect+Corona">Nconnect+Corona</option> <option value="Nconnect+TiaraMini">Nconnect+TiaraMini</option> </select> </div> </div> </div>';
            document.getElementById("devices").appendChild(div);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: I'm not able to use DOM in node js so I'm using body-parser but i'm not getting any efficient way to fetch data in array from front end using body-parser

Comment: Node.js is an offline/server-side javascript engine. It has no idea what a browser is, what a "page" is, what a "DOM" is, etc. etc: it is only concerned with running JS code that uses the JavaScrip API, enriched with [Node.js's standard library](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/), plus anything that additional packages that you installed can make happen. Any JS you intend to run in the browser, as a normal page script, _will not be running in Node_ and so _cannot use Node.js library calls_ which is where your script (and probably assumptions about what runs where) goes wrong.